# How to fetch initial values for session in svelte/sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper

I am using svelte/sapper with polka. I have some initial values to be fetched and stored in session from a web service before any page is loaded. What is the best recommended way to do this.

I tried doing this in _layout in the root. But as the fetch is asynchronous, values are not available in the first page load.

Answer (score 8):

Your layout components can use `preload`: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have more than 40 different pages in my app. I thought there could be a better way to manage this instead of checking this in each page preload.

Comment: @AnilSivadas If you use ``preload`` inside root ``_layout.svelte``, then you don't need to check in each page ``preload``.

Comment: I don't think preload works in layout file. Will try and update

Comment: It does. `preload` works in layout components and page components

Comment: How can you then access this variable in other server-side components? 
I can easily access it in <script>, but not in <script context="module">